# Center of uiviewcontroller with uinavigationcontroller

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ipad

I have 2 viewcontrollers with navigationcontroller (initWithRootView).
Then i added an activity to with

```
    CGPoint centerPoint = self.view.center;
    centerPoint.x -= self.view.frame.origin.x;
    centerPoint.y -= self.view.frame.origin.y;
    self.activity.center = centerPoint;
    self.activity.hidesWhenStopped = YES;
    [self.view addSubview:self.activity];
```

But one viewcontroller show activity center, one viewcontroller doesn't. I tried decrease y coordinated by Navigation's height and StatusBar's height, and get same result.

Comment: can you tell me what effort you want to achieve?

Comment: if you want the activityView in the center of `self.view`, you can test this code `actView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 67, 67);
    [self.view addSubview:actView];
    actView.center = self.view.center;`.

Comment: I want add activity to center of my viewcontroller's view.

Comment: I found the reason is "i didn't set frame for self.view".

Answer (score 0):

This line may be useful to you

```
- (void) viewDidLayoutSubviews 
{    

    self.activity.center = self.view.center; 

}
```